# Word Length Frequency Counter

Tags: java, counter, frequency, cpu-word

The code I have so far is

```
import java.io.*;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Curtis_Rodney_group8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("body.txt"); 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 

            String body;
            while ((body = br.readLine()) != null) { //read a line at a time
                out.println(body + "\n"); //disply the text untill the end of the file
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            out.println("File not found"); //if the file name is incorrect 


        }

    }
}
```

This code prints out the contents of the file `body.txt`, which is what I want.

However I now want to be able to have a word length frequency counter. For example the sentence `I am a man` would produce the output `2, 1, 1` (that is, two words of length 1, one word of length 2 and one word of length 3).

I am not a very experienced programmer and im also not looking for the direct answer. I am wondering how I now start the next bit of code, I think I use the body part as it is the string and I used the `body = br.readLine()`. I am unsure about how the next peace of code starts. Do I create a new class for the next bit of code. I hope you understand what I am asking, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should *split* each line in order to obtain the words. Then you should place the words into a *counter*. "Java split" and "java counter" are two search terms that may come in handy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the code below

```
public class FrequencyCounter {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("body.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        Map<Integer, Integer> lengthCounter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        String body;
        while ((body = br.readLine()) != null) { // read a line at a time
            System.out.println(body);
            String[] textSplit = body.split(" ");
            for(int i=0;i<textSplit.length;i++){
                if(lengthCounter.keySet().contains(textSplit[i].length())){
                    lengthCounter.put(textSplit[i].length(),lengthCounter.get(textSplit[i].length())+1);
                } else {
                    lengthCounter.put(textSplit[i].length(),1);
                }
            }
        }

        Iterator<Integer> iter = lengthCounter.keySet().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            int x=iter.next();
            System.out.println("Length : "+ x + " ... Freq : "+ lengthCounter.get(x));
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found"); // if the file name is
                                                // incorrect
    }

}
}
```

basically the idea here is that I am using a map to store each length and the frequency of words of that length in the string.

you perform a split to get each word from the line read from text file and then check if some words of the same length have been encountered earlier. If not you add that length to the Map else you increment the previous existing value for that length as key by 1.

The output I get for following code is :

```
hello
my name is Abhi
I am a guy

Length : 1 ... Freq : 2
Length : 2 ... Freq : 3
Length : 3 ... Freq : 1
Length : 4 ... Freq : 2
Length : 5 ... Freq : 1
```

where 
    hello
    my name is Abhi
    I am a guy

is the text read from file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't understand how helpful this is, I was trying to use arrays as I have a bit more knowledge with them but a map seems to be just as good even though I am a little unsure how some of the code works. Thanks you you're help, digidude. :)

Comment: @xRodderZz ... if you are having trouble understanding any part of code, just ask me. I can give you a solution that makes use of arrays too .... but that would make some assumptions.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply I have been working a lot. If you have a solution using arrays which won't take to much of you're time up could you please show me. I would like the understand how this is done with arrays. Don't worry if you are busy as you have already helped a lot @digidude

Answer (score 1):

following is the solution using array. This one should be easier to understand. The only downside of this solution is that we assume the maximum length of a word in your text could be 99.

```
int[] lengthCounterArray = new int[100];
```

If you can work with a similar constraint, this solution would work for you just fine.

```
public class FrequencyCounter{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("body.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        Map<Integer, Integer> lengthCounter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int[] lengthCounterArray = new int[100]; // assuming the maximum
                                                    // word length would be
                                                    // 99 for this program
        Arrays.fill(lengthCounterArray, 0);// initializing array values to 0
        String body;
        while ((body = br.readLine()) != null) { // read a line at a time
            System.out.println(body);
            String[] textSplit = body.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < textSplit.length; i++) {
                lengthCounterArray[textSplit[i].length()] += 1;
            }
        }

        for(int i =0;i<100;i++) {
            if(lengthCounterArray[i]==0)
                continue;
            else {
                System.out.println(" Length : "+i+" ... Freq : "+lengthCounterArray[i]);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found"); // if the file name is
                                                // incorrect
    }
}
```

Output for this piece of code is same as the previous one

```
hello
my name is Abhi
I am a guy
 Length : 1 ... Freq : 2
 Length : 2 ... Freq : 3
 Length : 3 ... Freq : 1
 Length : 4 ... Freq : 2
 Length : 5 ... Freq : 1
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have another class (let's call it FrequencyCounter) which takes a line of text (in a method - let's call it *processLine*), splits it into words, and uses the length of each word to update a counter for the specific length.  You could use a Map or a List, but it might be simpler and faster to use an array if you know the maximum possible word length (for example, an *int[100]* ought to be more than adequate in most cases). For example, for example, in *processLine()*, if you encounter the word "man", you set length to 3 and then update the counter (*this.counter[length]++*).

In your existing code, in the loop, you would call *myFrequencyCounter.processLine(body)* -- myFrequencyCounter is an instance of the new class (FrequencyCounter) which you need to instantiate before the start of the *while* loop.

When the while loop is done, myFrequencyCounter will have have its counter field, an array of ints where the index is the length and the value is the frequency count. You can give *FrequencyCounter* a method that prints the frequencies and call it after the *while* loop.

Comment: ....rightly said. array would have been such a simple solution if the max length was known :)

Comment: glorious arrayLists do not require a max length, they are dynamic in their size =)

Comment: Thanks for you're help guys, relieving me of a lot of stress.

Comment: @Ageoffan .. indeed ArrayLists are dynamic, but here the logic would require us to add values at particular indexes and not sequentially which would not allow the arraylist to grow and would result in ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception ....